# Zend 2 Storing value in session

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I've been trying to save a value to the session for over an hour now. The zend documentation is too confusing. They reference SessionManager, Session Container, Session save handlers, Session storage, Session validators.

I just want to store something to session and use it in another controller. but Zend makes it so difficult to do just that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use session container to save sessions.

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

public function indexAction()
    {
        $session = new Container('sessionsample');
        $session->offsetSet('id',1);
    }
```

Comment: Don't call `offsetSet()` directly, just do `$session->id = 1;`

Comment: Thanks. This worked. i saw somewhere that you use new Container() to get it as well.